# Clear Clipboard on app exit

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I know I can [place text on the clipboard and have it automatically removed when my app exists in .Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs5ebdfz(v=vs.110).aspx) .

Can I have the same functionality in UWP? Perhaps by somehow only placing a reference on the clipboard?

I tried the following but the text stays on the clipboard after app exit:

```
static void CopyToClipboardReference(string s)
{
    DataPackage dataPackage = new DataPackage();
    reference = s;
    dataPackage.SetDataProvider(StandardDataFormats.Text, CopyToClipboardAction);
    Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
}
static string reference;
static void CopyToClipboardAction(DataProviderRequest request)
{
    request.SetData(reference);
}
```

**EDIT**

[I found a way that *should* work according to the docs. But doesn't.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50087835/939213) To use delayed copying.

Answer (score 1):

You can just easily use [Clipboard.Clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard.clear#Windows_ApplicationModel_DataTransfer_Clipboard_Clear) Method to removes all data from the Clipboard in the [app's suspending](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Application#Windows_UI_Xaml_Application_Suspending) event witch will be triggered before the app was closed.

```
private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
    //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
    Clipboard.Clear();
    deferral.Complete();
}
```

See [UWP app lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle) to get more details about uwp app life cycle.

Comment: This won't work unless the app has focus. (And BTW see my edit.)

Comment: @ispiro I have replied your issue in the thread that you added in the **Edit** part, you can check my reply there (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087835/datapackage-setdataprovider-doesnt-wait-unlike-its-documentation-states)